# SQL Injection with Parameterized Queries in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-injection

So I have a bit of a problem. On a website I am developing I allow people to type in an address, once they hit a save button the address they type gets stored in my database.

I was (mistakenly) under the impression that using parameterized queries would help prevent SQL injection, here is my code once they press "save"

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=**********;Initial Catalog=********;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=*********");
SqlCommand updateMeeting = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [*******].[dbo].[**********] SET Title=@title, Date=@date, Location=@location, Announcement=@announcement WHERE Title = '" + commands[1] + "' AND Date = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(commands[2]) + "' AND Location = '" + commands[3] + "'", Conn);
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", newTitle);
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", newDate);
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", newLocation);
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@announcement", newBody);
updateMeeting.Connection.Open();
updateMeeting.ExecuteNonQuery();
updateMeeting.Connection.Close();
```

newTitle, newDate, newLocation and newBody are just string variables taken from their associated text boxes.

Rest assured that the commands array is sanitized. That's not where my injection problem comes into play.

and yet if I enter the following into my "location" text box the injection attack succeeds and a row gets added to my database

```
');INSERT INTO [********].[dbo].[*********] (Title) VALUES ('Injection'); --
```

So clearly I've missed something or I'm not understanding how these parameterized queries work. Isn't the entire point of this thing to make sure that the VarChar value for "location" is simply "');INSERT INTO [****].[dbo].[******] (Title) VALUES ('Injection'); --"

Shouldn't the injection attack fail?

Comment: `AND Location = '" + commands[3]` This isn't parametrization, just normal concatenation. So someone can write anything.

Comment: Your entire `WHERE` clause utilizes concatenation.

Comment: What is the value of `commands[3]` when the statement with the injection attempt is executed?

Comment: Are you sure that is not your commands array? Please add a simple Console.WriteLine(updateMeeting,CommandText) and you could see where the injection comes from

Comment: Yeah dude, you missed something alright...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really close - you have parameterized the values you are updating with, but not the values in your `WHERE` clause. Try something like this instead:

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=**********;Initial Catalog=********;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=*********");
SqlCommand updateMeeting = new SqlCommand(@"
    UPDATE [*******].[dbo].[**********] 
    SET Title=@title, 
        Date=@date, 
        Location=@location, 
        Announcement=@announcement 
    WHERE Title = @commands1
        AND Date = @commands2
        AND Location = @commands3",
        Conn);
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", newTitle);
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", newDate);
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", newLocation);
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@announcement", newBody);
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commands1", commands[1]);
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commands2", Convert.ToDateTime(commands[2]));
updateMeeting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@commands3", commands[3]);
updateMeeting.Connection.Open();
updateMeeting.ExecuteNonQuery();
updateMeeting.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Good answer, shows possible solution instead of just pointing out the problem +1.  OP may want to use `Parameters.Add("@title", SqlType.VarChar).Value = newTitle` for declaring paramaters.  `AddWithValue` has some risks depending on database type/size.

Comment: Thank you for your code and quick response. I'm glad this was caught and fixed before it went into production.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a parameterized query. In your `where` clause you're just concatenating strings:

```
"... WHERE Title = '" + commands[1] + "' AND Date = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(commands[2]) + "' AND Location = '" + commands[3] + "'"
```